# Can anyone confirm this Event Receiver behavior in SP2013/2016?

Tags: 2013, event-receivers, 2016, anonymous-authentication

I've done significant (though not extensive) testing in two separate environments - one SP2013 and one SP2016, and I've found that in the 2013 environment the AfterProperties of an ItemAdding event are empty when an item is created with anonymous users, but it is correctly populated in SP2016. I have not been able to find any documentation to support this, but is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

So, I think the problem wasn't so much the difference between SP2013 and 2016, but that in one environment anonymous users had access to read the entire list, but in the other they only had access to write items to the list. I believe this prevented the AfterProperties of the event from being populated, as the user did not have access to read the item it was creating.